# Intuition behind this q-binomial formula counting sums of subsets

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, binomial-coefficients, quantum-calculus

We have these transparent, motivating interpretations for binomial coefficients and their [$q$-analogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-analog).

$$
  \binom{n}{j} = \begin{matrix} \text{"The number of subsets of size $j$}\\ \text{of a set of size $n$."} \end{matrix}
  \qquad
  \newcommand{\qbinom}[2]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\\#2\end{bmatrix}_q}
  \newcommand{\qbinomsmall}[2]{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\end{smallmatrix}\right]_q}
  \qbinom{n}{j} = \begin{matrix} \text{"The number of subspaces of dimension $j$} \\ \text{of a vector space of dimension $n$} \\ \text{over a field with $q$ elements."} \end{matrix}
$$

In [Quantum Calculus](https://www.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-0071-7), before talking about this interpretation of the $q$-binomial coefficients, Kac and Cheung prove another formula for the $q$-binomials without motivating it. Let $\mathcal{A}_{n,j}$ denote the set of subsets of size $j$ of the set $\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$. Then

$$
  \qbinom{n}{j} = \sum_{S \in \mathcal{A}_{n,j}} q^{w(S) - \frac{1}{2}j(j+1)}
  \quad\text{where}\quad
  w(S) = \sum_{s\in S} s\,.
$$

What exactly is this sum counting? I don't immediately see this formula counting vector subspaces. Because it involves $\mathcal{A}_{n,j}$, it will clearly counts subsets of size $j$ of a set of size $n$ in the $q \to 1$ limit. But I don't see the inspiration for this formula. The $\frac{1}{2}j(j+1)$ bit is the minimum value that $w(S)$ can be, so maybe that's just there to *normalize* the power of $q$? And I don't see the connection, but this formula comes in the book just after the proof that $\qbinomsmall{n}{j}$ is a polynomial in $q$ of degree $j(n-j)$ with symmetric coefficients. So the coefficients of $\qbinomsmall{n}{j}$ will be the number of $S \in \mathcal{A}_{n,j}$ for which $w(S)$ is the same. But I'm still missing *why* this formula should give you those coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$  \newcommand{\qbinom}[2]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\\#2\end{bmatrix}_q}
  \newcommand{\qbinomsmall}[2]{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\end{smallmatrix}\right]_q}
\qbinomsmall{n}{j}$ is the generating function for partitions into at most $j$
parts and parts of size at most $n-j$.
(So partitions whose [Ferrers diagrams](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FerrersDiagram.html) fit within a $n-j$ by $j$ grid) We can represent such partitions
as $\pi=(\pi_1,\pi_2,\ldots,\pi_j)$ where $n-j\ge\pi_1\ge\pi_2\ge\cdots\ge\pi_j\ge0$. So $\qbinomsmall{n}{j}$ is the sum of $q^{w(\pi)}=q^{\pi_1+\cdots+\pi_j}$
over all such partitions. Then $(\pi_1',\pi_2',\ldots,\pi_j')
=(\pi_1+j,\pi_2+j-1,\ldots,\pi_j+1)$ satisfies $n\ge \pi_1'>\pi_2'>\cdots>\pi_j'\ge1$ so corresponds to a $j$-element subset of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
Moreover $\pi_1'+\cdots+\pi_j'=w(\pi)+\frac12j(j+1)$.